# HTML Email mixed (html & attachement) coming thoough as plain text

Tags: php, html, email, base64

I've got an HTML email being sent by PHP, with a pdf attached via base64 encoding. It all works, except the email comes through as plain text, so you see all HTML tags and base64 output - obviously not ideal. There must be something I'm missing here to ensure it gets read as HTML & attachment.

If anybody can help that would be fantastic!

My PHP:

```
<?php $to = $email;

$message = 'testing...';

$subject = 'Health Insurance Quote Request';

$headers = "From: Andy - CEO Health.com.au <" . strip_tags('info@health.com.au') . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: Andy - CEO Health.com.au <". strip_tags('info@health.com.au') . ">\r\n";

// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$email_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

//get PDF URL
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/doge.pdf')));

$email_message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/pdf\"};\n" . " name=\"$product\"\n" . 
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$product\"\n" . 
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

mail($email, $subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Example of output:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_xc9c6c260d1e99ba11f86b40c6c7848e0x"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--==Multipart_Boundary_xc9c6c260d1e99ba11f86b40c6c7848e0x
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

testing...

--==Multipart_Boundary_xc9c6c260d1e99ba11f86b40c6c7848e0x
Content-Type: {"application/pdf"};
 name="HeartPlus65"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="HeartPlus65"
cwt/SGdVm9X6LXQwvq03c+afGdAA9NlSAk1G3NyG2S5pDSY+CycXKDnuBJ5gFRupvZva0H2CXQqA
t9M6DlWx646bhhsx8NXdde0ES4z+8FP03XNEWTPMc/lWObbIG4ET4qxQ57eCm1V8RZOOzqG6+pu7
mYERMqHobI26KpfZYx27x8ESi65xkqOYkdbFIJ1qm2HXUEGZC0B1Jr2c6qmHeo3VULGurdIKhERP
Q6EJqtQ6rrWPbLiqzHgOlVLrfaIU8Zxe2SUhi4QTauK9G0/qbmjb2TD0HNkakoNlLbDzCql32d4A
khPjiE9rBQZGOvRvtxnEaGAlXimw7Vp4tIsqkjkI2JQ1upHBRgTA31CjqPNBjdM9ISRKHl9MLvc0
LeZUH8J7GNA1R+8mJvqkR0p5f7LZEbSkt7c2fopKX79LsEe2O7nv6qzJrc1xGreCsS

....
```

Comment: Try using SwiftMailer for this --- it handles attachments much more gracefully.

Answer (score -1):

It may be not having a -- at the end of the last boundary tag

ie $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

to $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

I'm not sure it there is a difference between multipart/mixed and multipart/alternative but this works for me

```
# Setup mime boundary
$mime_boundary = 'Multipart_Boundary_x'.md5(time()).'x';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";

$body    = "This is a multi-part message in mime format.\n\n";

# Add in plain text version
$body   .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
$body   .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"charset=us-ascii\"\n";
$body   .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body   .= $text_content;
$body   .= "\n\n";

# Add in HTML version
$body   .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
$body   .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
$body   .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$body   .= $html_content;
$body   .= "\n\n";

#Attachments
   if ($path!='' && $filename!=''){
    $file_size = filesize($path.$filename);
    $handle = fopen($path.$filename, "r");
    $filecontent = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $filecontent = chunk_split(base64_encode($filecontent));

    $body   .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $body .= $filecontent."\r\n\r\n";
    }
# End email
$body   .= "--$mime_boundary--\n";
```